# how come property exist on an object instance even when its prototype is changed?

Tags: javascript

When I executed following code, I expected that the last statement will give me undefined, but p1.lastname still has a value. Can somebody please explain?

```js
function Person() {
  this.name = "myname";
}
var p1 = new Person;
console.log(p1.name); // prints "myname"
Person.prototype.lastname = "mylastname";
console.log(p1.lastname); // prints "mylastname"
Person.prototype = {};
console.log("still there? " + p1.lastname); // prints "still there? mylastname"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `prototype` property has meaning inside JavaScript world but it's still a regular property which is a reference to the object representing a prototype.

That is, when you set `prototype` with an object having a `lastname` property, and then you create an instance of `Person`, this object is created from the prototype object with `lastname` property. The whole person has a reference to this prototype object.

Even when you change `Person` prototype, the `p1` variable is still a reference to an object which was instantiated using the old prototype and it retains a reference to this prototype instead of the new one.

If you try to create a `p2` variable and you instantiate `Person` again, this new person will be constructed using the empty prototype object.

### Answering to some OP comment...

> Thanks @Matías , creating a new Person instance did not have lastname
>   property. The thing I still did not understand is you said when you
>   set prototype with an object having a lastname property, and then you
>   create an instance of Person, this object is created from the
>   prototype object with lastname property But I have created first
>   instance before I added & deleted/override lastname property. –

Right, but I find no difference here.

As I said in my answer, prototypes are regular objects and `prototype` property is a regular property of any `function` instance.

For example, if you've defined a constructor function `function A() {}`, it has a default prototype - *an object with no properties* -. **Any object instantiated using `A` will share the same prototype**, thus, if you add a property to the prototype after instantiating any `A`, these instances then will have the property because `prototype` property is a reference to the same prototype object.

When you re-assign `prototype` property, you set another object and, in conclusion, now any instance of `A` will still reference the previous prototype, because they were instantiated using the first prototype object, not the second one.

Comment: Thanks @Matías , creating a new `Person` instance did not have lastname property. The thing I still did not understand is you said **when you set prototype with an object having a lastname property, and then you create an instance of Person, this object is created from the prototype object with lastname property** But I have created first instance before I added & deleted/override lastname property.

Comment: With the example that you have given, this makes sense. It is possible to have objects created with same Function to have different prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question to Matías (I can't comment because I don't have sufficient reputation yet), setting Person.prototype to {} makes it so that Person.prototype is no longer a reference to p1's prototype.  But if you reassign Person.prototype to its original value via the statement, Person.prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(p1); , changes to Person.prototype.lastname will again affect p1 (so long as p1 continues to be without its own lastname property.)

```
var p1 = new Person();
Person.prototype.lastname = "mylastname";
console.log(p1.lastname); // prints "mylastname"
Person.prototype = {};
Person.prototype.lastname = "mynewlastname";
console.log(p1.lastname); // still prints "mylastname"
Person.prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(p1);
Person.prototype.lastname = "mynewlastname";
console.log(p1.lastname); // now prints "mynewlastname"
```

This is analogous to what happens when you pass a reference to an object to a function: reassigning, deleting or adding new properties to the object will be visible outside of the function.  But reassigning the reference variable itself will unlink it so that it no longer affects the original object in question.

Comment: thanks for your response. My question to Matias was, I am  - setting `Person.prototype.lastname` and then assigning/overriding the prototype with { } - after I have created p1 instance. So how can it aftect p1 just in one statement (`Person.prototype.lastname="mylastname"`) and not in other (`Person.prototype = {}`)